# Capture Console Display (both input & output)

Tags: java, junit, io, console

I'm setting up some test cases for a console-based application in Java. Below is my code:

```
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("input 1\ninput 2".getBytes());
System.setIn(in); //feeds inputs

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(out)); //captures output

TestProgram.test();

String output = out.toString();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)));
System.out.println(output);
```

The application is a simple back and forth between the console and the user - the console asks a question, the user gives an answer. So, for example, the console might look like the following at the end of the interaction, given the inputs above:

```
Please enter a color: input 1
Please enter your name: input 2
```

...where `input 1` and `input 2` are the user's inputs, and the prompts are issued from `print` commands from `TestProgram.test()`.

I would like to capture what the console looks like at the end of the interaction (i.e., both inputs and outputs together), but it seems I can only capture input and output independently. How can I modify my code from above to capture the resulting console display, with inputs and outputs appropriately woven together?

Answer (score 0):

You could Log the `input` and `output` in a Array and push them together.

I don't understand **100%** but you can store them in a array.

```
String[] s = (out.toString() + in.toString()).split("\n");
for(String a : s) System.out.println(a);
```

Hope it helps